# how to combine two variables in jquery

Tags: javascript

I have two variables like :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    calc_my_project_ + count = Math.round( count * 268 / 100); // It shoud be calc_my_project_1 and next time it shoud be calc_my_project_2

    count += count + 1;
</script>
```

At now result is calc_my_project_ + count . how can I do this ?

EDIT : This is my main code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    var str = 'calc_my_project_';
    var str2 = 'my_pro_';
    var result = str + count;
    result = Math.round( @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ProgressPercent) * 268 / 100);
    var secresult = str2 + count;
    secresult = "-" + result + "px 0";

    var jq3 = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    jq3(document).ready(function () {
        jq3("#bar-pro-@barcount1st").css({ "background-position": secresult });
        if (@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ProgressPercent) == 100) {
            jq3("#bar-pro-@barcount1st").css({ "background-image": "none" });
            jq3("#bar-pro-@barcount2st").css({ "background-image": "none" });
        };
    });
    count++;
</script>
```

result and secresult return a fixed value I don't want to be like this .

Comment: In my opinion, you are doing way too much in one step. I would have to look at that for a second before I realized what you were doing.

Comment: You can't dynamically name vars. Only properties of objects.

Comment: Yes this is more than one step .. @Addison

Comment: I understand that it is more than one step. I am suggesting that you spread it apart just a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['my_project_' + count] = 'some value';

count++;
```

Comment: Then how to use this variable ? @Baszz

Comment: The same as you set it or as an actual object, like myObj.my_project_1.

Comment: Thank you very much @Baszz . but there is a problem . in my loop it return just last value .

Comment: I think that is another problem. You are probably actually only returning the last value. I don't know what it is you want to achieve so I can't help you out.

Comment: Yes I found it .. I put arrays out of loop , and it works now properly .

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    var str = 'calc_my_project_';

    var result = str + count = Math.round( count * 268 / 100); 

    count += count + 1;
</script>
```

Comment: I used this but result is a static variable yet . and it return to me a static value .

Answer (score 0):

You could store your calc_my_project_ variable in an array an iterate through it each time

```
obj = new Array(calc_my_project_1, calc_my_project2, ...);
obj[0] = 1;
obj[1] = 2;
...
```

Comment: count variable does not show to me 1 . it shows count , not 1 .

Comment: count is dynamic not static .

Answer (score 0):

Use an [array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp).

```
var myCount = new Array();
var count = 0;
$("#click").click(function() {
   myCount[count] = Math.round( count * 268 / 100);
    console.log(count + ' - ' + myCount[count]);
    count++;
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/yyakv/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set "global" variables, you can use the global variable container window :

```
window["calc_my_project_"+ count ] = Math.round( count * 268 / 100);
```

alternatively you can use eval but there are more risk involved :

```
eval ("calc_my_project_"+ count +"= Math.round( count * 268 / 100)") ;
```

else, if you don't need, global variables, you can use the solution provided by *Baszz*